# Delphi frames and forms

Tags: delphi

With regard to frames or forms, are there any memory consumption considerations as to which one uses more or less when dynamically created? I am developing an app that uses many controls and rather than adding all the controls to the main form I am looking at using either multiple frames or forms to accomplish this. If I am looking at this correctly, I think frames don't carry the burden of the extra windows controls that a form has.

Comment: There's no difference. And you'll not run out of memory due to GUI controls. That was a thing in the 80s. (Or are you planning to create millions of windows to be shown at the same time? If so, I'd expect you to run out of USER/GDI resources before memory becomes a problem. And the user would need a very large screen or a very large number of screens.)

Comment: Thanks for the info. the form creation will never hit millions. lol